# How does the distribution of "X - Xbar" change as the sample size is increased?

Tags: distributions, sample-size

Suppose we know that X has a normal distribution, but we don't know its mean and variance. As we collect observations, we compute the sample mean and use that as our best guess about E(X).

I am interested in the distribution of $X - \bar{X}$ and how it changes as we increase the sample size n. Specifically, I am interested in $P(X - \bar{X} > 1)$.

For example, suppose the first observation is $x_1 = 10$.  Then we are looking for the probability $P(x_2 - 10 > 1)$.  If $x_2$ turns out to be $12$, then $\bar{x}$ becomes $11$ [$= (10+12)/2$], and now I am interested in $P(x_3-11 > 1)$.

When n is large enough, xbar becomes very close to the population mean $\mu$, and $P(x-\bar{x}) = P(x - \mu)$, hence $P(x - \bar{x} > 1)$ is close to $P(z > 1/\sigma_x)$, where $z$ is the standard normal random variable.  I am interested in the distribution of $x - \bar{x}$ for smaller values of $n$.

If this is a known problem, may I ask you to please let me know what keywords I ought to look up?

Comment: Your probabilities are ambiguous.  Are you perhaps trying to ask about the distribution of $X-\bar X$ *conditional* on $\bar X$?  In any event, whatever probabilities you are interested in can be computed using standard formulas associated with bivariate Normal distributions (thereby giving you some good keywords).

Comment: You are right, it should be "conditional on Xbar".  Thank you for pointing this out and for giving me a keyword to work with.